# point feature duplicate in Qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

please how can I duplicate point feature in qgis.I have done copy and paste as directed by Qgis tips but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

To create duplicate features using copy-paste, try the below method and see if it works for you.

1. Add data to your map.
2. Click the yellow edit pencil to start editing.

[image]

3. Click the Select Features button.

[image: Select Features]

4. Click and drag a box around the features you want to duplicate. The selected features will change color.

[image: Selected Features]

5. On the keyboard, use Control-C (to copy), then Control-V (to paste). The features will be duplicated and you will get a confirmation message at the top of the map. If the keyboard shortcuts are not working for you, you can also use the Copy Features>Paste Features in the Edit menu to achieve the same result.

[image: Edit Menu]

[image: Confirmation Message]

6. Confirm that they have duplicated be selecting one of the expected duplicate features. There will be a message at the bottom of the map telling you what it has selected. In this case, I have selected one point on the map but it shows in the message that I have two features selected (that I duplicated in steps above).

[image: Selection Confirmation Message]

7. When you are done editing, the Save button will have activated. Be sure to click that so that your edits are saved.

[image: Save Button]

Comment: @IYKE Glad that worked for you! If you get a chance, please mark the question as answered so users know your issue has been addressed. Have a great day!